# background-image в IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

добрый день. в общем есть background-image:none; как сделать,что бы правило работало в IE8? жду ответа как соловей лета

Comment: Попробуйте : `background: transparent;` или `background: url('image'); 0 0 no-repeat transparent;`

Comment: спасибо,но чет нет) везде нормально,а в IE8 все как всегда. забыл написать,что этим условием я перебиваю bootstrap' овское правило с его картинкой

Comment: часто, чтобы перебить bootstrap, надо добавлять !important - мож это поможет

Comment: та пробовал через !important тоже,дескать,в первую очередь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

кому интересно. оказывается в бутстрапе было прописано правило для IE в виде filter и бла бла бла, пришлось залезть в bootstrap.css и делитнуть ненужное